# Any line by line debugging method in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, debugging, xcode4.2

I remember using turbo c++ compiler where I could do line by line code debugging technique, and was a great tool for both learning and debugging. Is there the similar way to do in Xcode. Are there any other way rather that putting break points??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From **Product->Debug** menu (Xcode 4.+), try the following options (they provide quite a similar functionality ):

- Step Over (F6)
- Step Into (F7)
- Step Out (F8)

---

**Manual :** [Debugging with Xcode](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/courses/cs106b/handouts/09m-debugging-with-xcode.pdf)